# Gridview failed to display data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

newbi to .Net code; I appreciate if someone can answer this fairly easy question. I made sure that the SQL command is returning the data, but I cant make it populate and display the datagrid.

Here is the code

```
   cmd.Connection = conn;
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    var dt = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    //DataGrid GV1 = new DataGrid(); 
    //Response.Write(ds.Rows[0][0].ToString()); 
    //GV.DataSource = dt;
    GV.DataSource = dt.Tables[0];
    GV.DataBind();
    Response.Write("Hello");
```

Comment: Is `AutoGenerateColumns` set to true?

Comment: Thank you so much...I know it is something simple :)